# Create nlb-ip loadbalancers in kubernetes created in AWS through Kops

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kops

I have a Kubernetes cluster created through the Kops tool. And I have a requirement to expose my service using a network load balancer. And the target groups should be based on IP based. I have found the answer using the annotation mentioned in the site https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/guide/service/nlb_ip_mode/.

This seems to work only when we have the cluster created through EKS. Since I'm using a kops tool could you please help me in installing *alb load balancer controller* which is one of the requirements to create a nlb-IP loadbalancers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use IP targets, not instance targets, you need to use a CNI that provisions VPC IPs per pod. Those are:

- [Cilium with ipam](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/networking/cilium/#enabling-cilium-eni-ipam)
- Lyft VPC
- AWS VPC

Then you need to install [AWS LB controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/latest/), which supports this mode both for NLB and ALB. I would wait until kOps 1.20, which will support installing this controller out of the box, including the various permissions that needs setting.

Comment: I was following the steps provided in  https://github.com/aws/eks-charts/tree/master/stable/aws-load-balancer-controller. However, steps are related to eks. I'm finding how to add the policies in the pods.

Comment: If you refer to the IAM policy, you can attach as described here: https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/iam_roles/#adding-external-policies or here https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/iam_roles/#use-existing-aws-instance-profiles. But this is the part that will be much smoother in kOps 1.20. kOps will create all if this.